# Change Perforce files' recursive permissions

Tags: perforce

I have multiple directories that have +w (Always writable in workspace).
How do I change all files to keep all permissions as is, and remove the +w if exists. Need the p4 command (I know p4 edit -t is per file type...).
Some files are text, some are binaries...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This'll do it:

```
p4 -F "%type%@%depotFile%" files ... | grep -e ".*w.*@.*" | sed -e "s/\(.*\)w\(.*\)@\(.*\)/edit -t \1\2 \"\3\"/" | p4 -x - run
```

Note that you need "grep" and "sed" -- if you're on Windows (like I am) I recommend the versions that come with Cygwin.  :)